# Land coverage by buildings

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I would like to get information about land coverage by buildings using Google Maps.
I presume this would be possible using Google API / other mechanism but I dont know how.
For example (the direction services API) would provide distance between start and destination.

Providing the lat lang for 2 points defining a rectangular area, is it possible to calculate the building coverage area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create an array that defines the 4 vertices of this area.
   lets assume you have the give 2 LatLngs `{lat:1,lng:2}` and `{lat:3,lng:4}` the resulting array would be:

   ```
       path=[
             new goo.LatLng(1,2),
             new goo.LatLng(1,4),
             new goo.LatLng(3,4),
             new goo.LatLng(3,2),
            ]
   ```
2. use the method [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(path)`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) of the geometry-library to calculate the area.

Example(calculates the area of the map-viewport): http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/WfQpj/

Comment: Thanks for the input. I can see that area calculation comes up.
I am looking at getting the land coverage area **by Buildings** only.
Is there a way to calculate that for the given bounds.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the example calculates the area based on the bounds of the map(so there are given bounds), of course you can use the bounds of a building instead